# fail to access property in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I intend to get "0,0,0,0" but only get ",,,". It seems my way of access class property in coffeescript is not functioning properly.

```
class Tetris
    @array: []

    constructor: (@width, @height) ->
        @array = new Array(@width*@height)
        @array.map (item, i) -> this[i]=0

    to_s: ->
        array_item for array_item in this.array

$ ->
    t = new Tetris 2,2
    alert t.to_s()
```

The compiled javascript is as follows:

```
(function() {
  var Tetris;
  Tetris = (function() {
    Tetris.array = [];
    function Tetris(width, height) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.array = new Array(this.width * this.height);
      this.array.map(function(item, i) {
        return this[i] = 0;
      });
    }
    Tetris.prototype.to_s = function() {
      var array_item, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
      _ref = this.array;
      _results = [];
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        array_item = _ref[_i];
        _results.push(array_item);
      }
      return _results;
    };
    return Tetris;
  })();
  $(function() {
    var t;
    t = new Tetris(2, 2);
    return alert(t.to_s());
  });
}).call(this);
```

Comment: `this` doesn't point to the array inside `map()`. It would probably work if you  used `=>` for the map function, but ilia's method is best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
class Tetris
    constructor: (@width, @height) ->
        @array = for x in [ 0 ... (@height*@width)] then 0
        console.log @array
    to_s: ->
        array_item for array_item in this.array

$ ->
    t = new Tetris 2, 2
    alert t.to_s()
```

or this

```
class Tetris
    constructor: (@width, @height) ->
        @array = (0 for x in [0...(@height*@width)])
        console.log @array
    to_s: ->
        array_item for array_item in this.array

$ ->
    t = new Tetris 2, 2
    alert t.to_s()
```

They both generate the same javascript

This is the section covering list comprehension.
http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#loops

Comment: Thanks! This works!! Could you tell me why my code is not working? I am pretty new to Coffeescript and Javascript. Still struggling to learn the nuance of the class and inheritance.

Comment: is Array.prototype.map defined?

Comment: I tried under REPL: coffee> [1,2,3].map (item, i) -> this[i]=0
I can get [ 0, 0, 0 ].

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` is available in node, but not in most browsers AFAIK.

Comment: @lkahtz If you were trying to use the underscore `map` function, it isn't on Arrays by default.  You would have to do `_(@array).map` to get the function... though I wouldn't recommend using `map` for something like this... the purpose of `map` is to return a new collection where each item is the result of a mapping function... not to mutate the context like you are doing.  A more semantically correct way to act on every item is to use `_(@array).each`.